Find the value of $a$ so that the equation $|a^3+a^2x|+|a^2x+1| =(1-a^3) $ has not less than 6 integral solutions
The solution in my assignment's answer key is $(-\infty, -5) \cup (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} , \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})$.
I tried solving it by finding out the turning points of the graph of LHS and found an inequality:
$$\frac1{a^2} - a^2 \gt4.$$
That is what I could reason out. Any help will be appreciated.
(Squaring the terms results in a monstrous equation.)

The solution for $\frac1{a^2}-a^2\gt4$ is $-\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}\lt a \lt \sqrt{\sqrt5-2}$, $a\ne0$. This is not what your key suggests. So this inequality is probably wrong.

I’m getting a different answer: $(-\infty,-5]\cup[-\frac1{\sqrt5},\frac1{\sqrt6}]$. Wolfram Alpha also disagrees with your answer. Maybe there is a typo somewhere in your post.

The answer you got is correct(there was a typo in my post, i apologize ). Please share your method to solve this question.

My approach would be to dispense with any attempt at elegance, and go back to basics.  So, my attack would start with [1] In terms of the (unknown) fixed constant $~a,~$ under what circumstances is the expression $~(a^3 + a^2x)~$ non-negative, rather than negative? [2] In terms of the (unknown) fixed constant $~a,~$ under what circumstances is the expression $~(a^2x + 1)~$ non-negative, rather than negative?  Based on the answers to [1] and [2], I would then divide the analysis into mutually exclusive cases, and slowly/carefully examine each case.

Please see this article on MathSE protocol.

Imagine the number line. An expression $|x-y|$ could be seen as the distance between the numbers $x$ and $y$ on that line.
The LHS is the sum of two moduli, so is non-negative. Hence the RHS is non-negative, too. So we get that $a^3\le 1$ (and $a\le1$). It means that on the number line the numbers $a^3$ and $1$ are in this order: first $a^3$, and then to the right of it there is $1$. And the RHS (although there is no explicit sign of absolute value) is the distance between those two numbers.
Let us transform the LHS into $$|-a^2x-a^3|+|-a^2x-1|.$$ We can do that because $|y|=|-y|$ for any $y$. The logic behind this transformation is to get expressions of the forms $|y-1|$ and $|y-a^3|$ which are the distances from $y$ to the numbers $1$ and $a^3$. In this case we get the sum of the distances from $-a^2x$ to $-a^3$ and from $-a^2x$ to $1$.
This sum of distances is equal to the distance between $a^3$ and $1$. What does it mean? That the number $-a^2x$ is between those numbers on the number line! Or, speaking algebraically,
$$\left\{\begin{align}
a^3&\le-a^2x\\
-a^2x&\le 1
.\end{align}\right.$$
We see that $a=0$ actually is a possible answer to our problem. Because any $x$ satisfies these two inequalities. Going further we assume $a\ne0$. The inequalities become:
$$\left\{\begin{align}
a^2(a+x)&\le0\\
-x&\le \frac1{a^2}
.\end{align}\right.$$
$$\left\{\begin{align}
x&\le-a\\
x&\ge -\frac1{a^2}
.\end{align}\right.$$
Or, simply $$-\frac1{a^2}\le x\le-a.$$
Now begins the tedious part, where we consider different possible values of $a$ and see how many integer values $x$ can take. If $0\lt a\lt1$, then $-a$ is strictly between $-1$ and $0$. So if we want $x$ to take at least $6$ integer values, we have to have $-\frac1{a^2}\le-6.$ Solving this, we get $$0\lt a\le\frac1{\sqrt6}.$$
Now consider $-1\lt a\lt0$. In this case $-a$ is strictly between $0$ and $1$. In comparison to the previous case, $x$ can now take the integer value $0$. So we have to have $-\frac1{a^2}\le-5.$ Solving this, we get $$-\frac1{\sqrt5}\le a\lt0.$$
If $a\lt-1$, then $-\frac1{a^2}$ is strictly between $-1$ and $0$. So it must be that $-a\ge5$, or $$a\le-5.$$
The cases $a=\pm1$ are left. It’s easy to see they don’t give solutions. Combining everything together we get the answer:
$$a\in(-\infty, -5]\cup[-\frac1{\sqrt5}, \frac1{\sqrt6}].$$

Thank you very much!
